# timer that shows how many seconds you have to wait before using a button in java

Tags: java, swing, timer, jbutton

I'm trying to create a game similar to League of Legends for practice and i want to make it so that when you click a button the button disables for 5 seconds while the button text changes to a timer that says how many seconds you have to wait before using that button again. I successfully made the button disable for 5 seconds but now im stuck on the timer part.

I tried creating a variable then divide it by 1000(i had to divide it by 1000 because im also using this variable to the other timer that disables the button) but i get a error message:

> The method setText(String) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Here is the code for what i said above:

```java
ImageIcon qAbilityIcon = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("images/Jaws_of_the_Beast.png"));

JButton qAbilityBtn = new JButton("Q");

// creates a timer that disables the button for 5 seconds
int qCDTime =(int)5000;
                
Timer qCooldown = new Timer(qCDTime, new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        qAbilityBtn.setEnabled(true);
        qAbilityBtn.setText("Q");
        }
});
qCooldown.setRepeats(false);

JLabel qAbility = new JLabel();
qAbility.setIcon(qAbilityIcon);
qAbility.setBounds(90, 350, 64, 64);
qAbilityBtn.setBounds(90, 315, 64, 35);
qAbilityBtn.setOpaque(false);
qAbilityBtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
qAbilityBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
qAbilityBtn.setFocusable(false);
qAbilityBtn.addActionListener(e -> {
    int minQDmg = 25;
    int maxQDmg = 75;

    int qDmg = (int)(Math.random() * (maxQDmg - minQDmg + 1) + minQDmg);
    abilityLabel.setText("You dealt " + qDmg + " damage!");
    abilityLabel.setBounds(170, 10, 200, 50);
    qAbilityBtn.setEnabled(false);

    // here im getting the error
    qAbilityBtn.setText(qCDTime / 1000);

    qCooldown.start();
});
```

I know that this might not work but can someone tell me why I'm getting that error and how I can fix it.

Also if this doesn't work(which most probably won't work) how do I make the timer that shows you how many seconds you have to wait.

I also google'd this up but i didnt find what I needed or atleast I didn't know how to implement it in my code.

[This](https://www.codepile.net/pile/qJvnR5Jv) is my Main file.

[This](https://www.codepile.net/pile/J4yzBdMr) is my Game file

P.S: i apologize for my bad english and for my bad explaining skills!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to understand what the error is telling you. You are giving an argument of type `int` to a function that requires an argument of type `String`. In order to resolve the error you can replace this line:

`qAbilityBtn.setText(qCDTime / 1000);`

with this:

`qAbilityBtn.setText(String.valueOf(qCDTime / 1000));`

That will solve the error, but I am pretty sure that the code will not do what you want it to do since only the current value of `qCDTime / 1000` will be displayed on the button, it will not be updated.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many ways to do this but this is what I would do. Most of what is below is typical boiler plate on how GUI's should be layed out.

- use a Swing timer to control the event.
- the button and timer share the listener and use an `actionCommand` to determine which component triggered the event.
- the default countDown time is 5 seconds.  The timer issues an event every second.
- the button is displayed with the remaining seconds.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ButtonTimer extends JPanel {
    
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Button Timer Demo");
    JButton b = new JButton("Click Me!");
    MyActionListener mal = new MyActionListener();
    Timer t = new Timer(0, mal);
    
    public ButtonTimer() {
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        add(b);
        b.addActionListener(mal);
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 40));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        t.setDelay(1000);
        t.setActionCommand("timer");
    }
    
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 50);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new ButtonTimer());
    }
    
    public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public int seconds = 0;
        
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("timer")) {
                if (seconds == 0) {
                    t.stop();
                    b.setText("Click Me!");
                } else {
                    b.setText(seconds + "");
                    seconds--;
                }
            } else {
                // must be button
                if (seconds == 0) {
                    // only do button action if seconds == 0
                    seconds = 5;
                    // start timer
                    t.start();
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```